# PHP PDO: Call to a member function prepare() & list?

Tags: php, pdo

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Is what I am getting when I try to do:

```
$sql = $connect->prepare ("SELECT id, pwd, firstname, lastname, approved, user_level FROM users WHERE $user_cond AND banned = 0"); // SELECT
$sql->execute ();
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num = $connect->rowCount();
```

Im holding on rewriting my system, taking out all mysql_* and make use of pdo instead.

This is what was before:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`pwd`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`approved`,`user_level` FROM users WHERE 
           $user_cond
            AND `banned` = '0'
            ") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

What have I done wrong?

And with list() I have:

```
list($id,$pwd,$firstname,$lastname,$approved,$user_level) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

instead of mysql_fetch_row($result); what should I do in PDO?

My PDO object/connection:

```
try{
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset:UTF-8", DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
  die('Could connect to the database because: ' .$pe->getMessage());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   prepare() on a non-object

usually means that something failed and your variable is not what you expect it to be. `$connection` is probably `false`.

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
list($id,$pwd,$firstname,$lastname,$approved,$user_level) = $sql->fetch();
```

Also call `rowCount` on the statement, not on the connection:

```
$sql->rowCount();
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your code in order. Somehow that `$connection` isn't created and what you supplied isn't enough to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Could it be because $connect is outside the function? should i make it global? I just tried with global $connect; after the $connect line, didnt fix the issue

Comment: You need `global $connect` inside the function where you want to use it, not where you create it.

Comment: Thank you now something is happening almost.. On $num = $connect->rowCount(); I am receiving Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::rowCount()

Answer (score 1):

Since you using prepare, you should make the $cond a named parameter and then do this:
in this example the condition is just user_id, but you can have multiple conditions and multiple named parameters, just bind() each one the same way

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare ("SELECT id, pwd, firstname, lastname, approved, user_level FROM users WHERE user_id = :cond AND banned = 0"); 
$sth->bindParam(':cond', $some_user_id);
$sth->execute ();
$a = $sth->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

The $a will be your assiciate array, print_r($a) to see what's in it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a scope issue.

Are you assigning `$connect` within a function, class, namespace or are you running prepare in a function, class or namespace ?

if your assigning `$connect` within a function then that function should return the PDO Connection. I would introduce a static instance like so:

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    private $instance = null;
    public static function Instance()
    {
        if(self::$instance == null)
        {
            self::$instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __construct(){}
    private function __connect()
    {
        try 
        {
            parent::__construct("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset:UTF-8", DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION))
        }catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

then use like so:

```
$Database = Database::Instnace();

$Database->prepare("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely due to the MySQL connection failing - therefor `$connect` is not a valid PDO object - so as the error says, you're trying to call a method on an object which doesn't support it. What does your connection handling code look like? Did you check if a connection was successfully created?

Comment: Looks ok. Hvae you tried doing a var_dump() of $connect immediately before the ->prepare() call? PDO can do errors in two ways: exceptions and returning boolean FALSE. Your setup could doing the boolean version, so your catch block would never fire.

Comment: I get "NULL" when i do var_dump, is this bad? Could it be because $connect is outside the function? should i make it global? I just tried with global $connect; after the $connect line, didnt fix the issue

Comment: There we go. Scoping issue. You have to do a `global $connect` call BEFORE you use $connect anywhere in a function. PHP won't parse ahead through a function and "retroactively" apply any global directives.